# How to save files for Video Game Design across multiple computers?

Tags: cloud

3 Friends of mine and I are creating a video game team and are starting to create our first game. We will all be be at different locations and we need a program, software, or something to where we can save our project instantly across all of our computers, and have the ability to edit the code at the same time (allow two or more of our programmers to edit the code at the same time so they can work together). It would need to be a free program as we have a very limited budget.

Comment: Do you mean something like git, or svn, or do you mean for your assets? http://www.sitepoint.com/version-control-software-2014-what-options/

Comment: Similar to git, yes. I created a project on source forge, but it is a little     non-user-friendly IMO. It would need to allow us to work on the same file at the same time all at once (if possible?)

Comment: Git / SVN / Mercurial are just the backend, there are plenty of nice GUI front ends for them. I'd recommend git with github or bitbucket, and find a GUI front end you like - might even be included with your IDE?

Comment: Now, How would I be able to make it to where we could all edit the same file at the same time together? Since we are all at different places, it is hard trying to explain over text or stuff what to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Git / Github / GitLab - https://about.gitlab.com/ (An easy solution if you have your own server)